# How To Read A Text File Via Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, text-files

I am trying to read from a text file, but whenever the program gets to my while loop it just skips over it. I used a previous example I had to check to see if I did it correctly, but it doesn't seem to be working this time.

EDIT: to clarify, the while with "b++" under it is being skipped.

EDIT 2: Updated code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ToDoItem td = new ToDoItem();
    ToDoList tl = new ToDoList();

    File file = new File("ToDoItems.txt");
    Scanner ReadFile = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String inputline;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the list maker!" + "\n" + "Please start typing.");

    try (PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new File("ToDoItems.txt"))) {

        do {
            System.out.println("add to the list? [y/n]");
            inputline = keyboard.nextLine();

            if ("y".equals(inputline)) {
                fout.print(td.getDescription() + "\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Here is the list so far:");

                while (ReadFile.hasNext()) {
                    String listString = ReadFile.nextLine();
                    list.add(listString);

                }
            }
        } while ("y".equals(inputline));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Ideally I want it to print a part of the Array each time it passes through the while loop. But it just ends up skipping over it.
I checked the text file itself, and it does have the information I want to print to it. Yet for some reason the scanner won't read it properly.

Comment: which `while` is being skipped?

Comment: Are you sure it's being skipped? I would guess that this line: `stringArray[b] = ReadFile.nextLine();` would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: the second while, the one with "b++".  I know it is being skipped because I tried to print a simple "can you see me" message under it, and it never showed.

The out of bounds exception is another problem I don't know how to do. But I am trying to get the error to pop up first and see if I can figure it out then.

Comment: `String[] stringArray = new String[b];` the array is size 0, which is what @aryn.galadar was getting at. Set it to something other than `b` because `b` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you are trying to read a file that you are currently using, try close the `fout` object before read it, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("ToDoItems.txt");
    ToDoItem td = new ToDoItem();
    ToDoList tl = new ToDoList();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String inputline;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the list maker!" + "\n" + "Please start typing.");
    try (PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    //                                       ^^ here
        do {
            System.out.println("add to the list? [y/n]");
            inputline = keyboard.nextLine();

            if ("y".equals(inputline)) {
                fout.print(td.getDescription() + System.lineSeparator());
            } else {
                // Important line is here!
                fout.close(); // <--- Close printwriter before read file

                System.out.println("Here is the list so far:");
                Scanner ReadFile = new Scanner(file);

                while (ReadFile.hasNext()) {
                    String listString = ReadFile.nextLine();
                    list.add(listString);
                }
            }
        } while ("y".equals(inputline));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it.

May I ask why that worked. Is it simply because I can't print to the console when it is open? I remember being able to leave it open when writing it to a text file.

Comment: I'm reading why this is not possible haha I believe is because `fout` won't flush your data when you call `fout.print(string)` method so you have to manually call to `fout.flush()` after every print call, or `fout.close()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

`String[] stringArray = new String[b];` is problematic as your `int b = 0;`.

Also, it seems like you do not know how large your array will even be. I would suggest you use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. That way you will not need a counter, just add to the ArrayList.

It would be better to `try` and `catch` your `FileNotFoundException` instead of throwing at the `main` but I guess you know that your file will always be there.

Comment: Okay, I believe I added the arrayList properly. I have it where every time it goes through the second while loop, it will add the next line of the file to the arrayList.

But I still don't know why it is skipping that while loop.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code. As of right now it just prints "[ ]". So it is safe to say that in the while loop it doesn't add anything as it passes.